# VBA Array/Sharepoint confusion

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sharepoint

I am working on a project that involves pulling information from Sharepoint, different (but known) sheets. What I am attempting to do is use `TestNameCaller` to do the following:

Go through, check the sheet. If the cell has a name in it, (test in this case), it will then call the array, then load variable based on j (in this case 1, which correlates to the 'Tests' book). Then use the case to filter though which information gets pulled, and where to put it in the main sheet.

Below is what I have. The principle is for Cells(5,3), to reference the Sharepoint link, specific worksheet, and cell.

```
Function TestNameCaller(Arrname() As Variant) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim link As String

j = 1

For i = 3 To 8
    If Cells(3, i) <> "" Then
        name = Cells(3, i)
        link = Arrname(j)
        Select Case name

            Case "Test"
                Cells(5, 3) = Workbooks(link).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 7)
        End Select
    End If
Next i

End Function

-----------------------------

Sub ArrayCaller()
Dim fString As String
Dim Arrname As Variant

Arrname(1 To 2)
Arrname(1) = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/Sheets/Test.xlsx"
Arrname(2) = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/Sheets/Book.xlsx"

fString = TestNameCaller(Arrname())
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be assigning using value for example name =Cells(3,i) would be name = Cells(3, i).value and same principle for testing a cells value for <> "". What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Im not getting an error at all. I press the 'Run button' while my selection is in the Function, and it pulls up my Macro list, and the TestNameCaller isnt even there to run (as Function or Sub, ive tried both)

Comment: Press the run button while your selection is in the `Sub`, not while in the `Function`

Comment: @QHarr FYI, in a statement such as `name = Cells(3, i)`, the default property of the range object is the `Value` property, so `name = Cells(3, i)` is equivalent to `name = Cells(3, i).Value`.  It causes less problems if programmers get into the habit of explicitly coding the property they are using (because `Value` won't **always** be used if no property is specified, sometimes it uses the `Range` itself) but in that specific statement it is not an issue.

Comment: `Arrname(1 To 2)` is not valid VBA